# Elasicsearch curator reindexing

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I'm new to curator for elasticsearch and trying to make re-indexing but I need to search indexes that contains word "debug" inside index.

I was trying to do it with

```
filters:
- filtertype: pattern
  kind: regex
  value: '^*.debug.*$'
```

But it doesn't work properly.
From devtools in kibana if I will do `get *.debug*/_search` it shows how it should be. But how can I do the same with actionfile?

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression does not match the `GET` statement.

`GET *.debug*/_search`

will not match the same indices as

`value: '^*.debug.*$'`

but `value: '^*.debug*$'` might match the same query string.